# How should I prevent images from floating between list and paragraph before

Tags: floats, lists, page-breaking

I have a list which has some text that describes the list and an image that gets in between of those:

[image]

The LaTeX code looks similar to this:

```
\begin{figure}...\end{figure}

\textbf{\textit{Technische Kriterien}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Bla bla bla...
    \item Bla bla bla...
    \item Bla bla bla...
    \item Bla bla bla...
    \item Bla bla bla...
    \item Bla bla bla...
\end{itemize}
```

How can I prevent the image to get in between of the paragraph before the list?

I tried `\FloatBarrier` as suggested in this answer, but it didn't work. Using `\goodbreak` before "Technische Kriterien" without `FloatBarrier` worked. With `\FloatBarrier`, it didn't work.

Is this a good way to solve this problem? How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Try inserting a `\par\nobreak` after `\textbf{\textit{Technische Kriterien}}`. The problem is not so much with the float, but with the text around it, so there's no use in fiddling with `\FloatBarrier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the "Technische Kriterien" part is some kind of a heading, you should use some heading-like command that is automatically kept together with the following text. You could try something like

```
\begin{figure}
…
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Technische Kriterien}
\begin{itemize}
    \item …
    \item …
    \item …
    \item …
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: And what should I do if it is not some kind of heading?

Comment: @moose In this case you could try the solution that Werner gave in [his comment to your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121725/how-should-i-prevent-images-from-floating-between-list-and-paragraph-before/121733?noredirect=1#comment271922_121725). I haven't checked, if that one works, but from Werner's experience I guess it should. ;-)